# FragmentTabsPager - tabs issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

I have followed the ABS example of FragmentTabsPager, but I'm facing this problem:

- Activity A has two fragments: F1, F2 which are added in onCreate() method of the A with use of the TabsAdapter.
- Activity A has the option to refresh fragments which is done according to 
  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity
- Activity A has the option to launch Activity B, which adds item to F1 (F1 thus, needs to be updated)

However, after finishing B, the fragments are not attached to A anymore. After some debugging, I found that the onCreate() method of A is called after finishing B with savedInstanceState containing this entry:

```
android:support:fragments=android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState$41bfffe0
```

My understanding is that FragmentActivity saved the fragments before launching B and after relaunching A, it tries to restore them. With a little of tracing I found that after finishing B, these actions are called:

```
Activity A: constructor called
Fragment F1: constructor called
Fragment F2: constructor called
Fragment F1: onAttach
Fragment F1: onCreate
Fragment F2: onAttach
Fragment F2: onCreate
Activity A: onCreate
Activity A: TabsAdapter created    
TabsAdapter: addTab android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec@41d949f8
Fragment F1: constructor called
TabsAdapter: addTab android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec@41d965d0
Fragment F2: constructor called
Fragment F1: onActivityCreated
Fragment F1: onCreateLoader
Fragment F2: onActivityCreated
Fragment F2: onCreateLoader
Activity A: onStart
Fragment F1: onResume
Fragment F1: onCreateLoader
Fragment F2: onResume
Fragment F2: onCreateLoader
Activity B: onStop
Fragment F1: onLoadFinished
Fragment F2: onLoadFinished
```

There are 2 instances of each fragment, and the showing fragments are not attached to activity.

How can I solve this? What am I doing wrong? Maybe if there was a way how to get the restored fragments?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are ultimately trying to achieve is unclear. Is `Activity` B intended just to add onto the data that `Fragment` F1 displays? Or is it trying to display the same instances of `Fragment`s F1 and F2? If you give more info about the current app architecture, and what you want each piece to do, it will help us give a better answer.

Comment: @Steven Activity B only adds a new item, which F1 should display. What architecture information would be helpful? Please, specify, so I can give you what is needed.

Comment: @Steven I have finally found out how to get the restored fragments: `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:VIEW_PAGER_RESOURCE_ID:TAB_ORDER")` and it is working now! However, it doesn't seem to me like a correct approach. Do you have any idea how to notify fragments contained in activity to update their UI?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, here is what I would suggest:

1. Since `Fragment`s F1 and F2 live in `Activity` A, `Activity` B **should not create, or attempt to interact** with either `Fragment`.
2. Have `Activity` A start `Activity` B using [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), and have B pass back the item (to be added to `Fragment` F1) to A.
3. `Activity` A should handle sending the new item to `Fragment` F1 using an `interface` (like you've done).
4. Upon receiving the new item (in your `interface` method) from `Activity` A, `Fragment` F1 should then update its data and refresh its `View`s.

Another thing to note, ensure that your `Activity` A only adds your `Fragment`s once in `onCreate`, it can use the `savedInstanceState` to know if it is being recreated or if it's the first creation of it. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html.

### **Edit**

Ah now I see more of what you are asking. There are several ways you can go here.

1. Use the `FragmentManager` and the tag trick to get the `Fragment`s out of the `ViewPager`, and update them as needed.

   - This is slightly more dangerous as it will return `Fragment`s that may not be in `onResume` and need to be checked before being interacted with.
2. Decouple the model from the controller, as in put your data into a static singleton, SQLite DB, or even preferences. This would allow other portions of the app to access and edit the data, without the need of passing it around.

   - In `onResume`, your `Fragment`s would then need to check and update their data, in case it had been changed.
   - Your `Activity` will also need to give them a refresh signal via an `interface` method if the `Fragment`s are already in `onResume` when the change occurs.
   - OR, use a `Loader` in your `Fragment`s to monitor the data set and have it autoupdate the `Fragment`'s UI via `interface` callbacks.